# Why is char* t not point to NULL defined before ctime_r?

Tags: c, linux, initialization

Before I use `ctime_r`,I defined `char* t` instead of `char* buf[32]` by mistake.I thought `char* t` is point to NULL,and there will be a error after using `ctime_r`,like `stycpy(t,"hello");`.But I was surprised to find that `char* t` is not point to NULL as usual.Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I thought `char* t` is point to `NULL`,*

No, that's not true. There is no universal rule for initialization, it depends on the storage duration of the object.

In your case, most likely, the variable is a local scope one and has automatic storage duration, hence, unless initialized explicitly, the initial content is indeterminate.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.7.9/P10

> *If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate*

Comment: Oh,I asked a silly question A variable defined within the function is automatic,I knew that a long time ago.Maybe I use 'strcpy' recently,the char* t is often point to 'NULL' which misled and confused me .Thank you for your professional answer to a stupid question!Sorry to trouble you!